# HTML5 Application (server or client side) using phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I need to develop an HTML5  mobile business application using PhoneGap. After finishing my application I want to make it a native app.

Can anyone tell me What is the best way to  do it

1. Develop an application using HTML5 and Javascript, call web services from Javascript and embed it in a native app using PhoneGap
2. Develop an application using HTML5, Javascript and PHP. (server side). use PHP to call web services. use PhoneGap to call server urls.

1st one seems more native and fast. 2nd one seems more flexible and secure, but I need an additional server for that.

so what is the best solution?

Comment: Thats for to wide a question, like; can you tell me how to make a meal or my father using a kitchen and some utensils. This site is for specific development questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I agree this is too wide a question, I would go with #1 because certainly in the case of Apple and iOS I am pretty sure you would not be able to get an app past Apple's gatekeepers if it loaded remote code (Javascript, etc).

Calling out to a web service for remote data via AJAX, etc is fine however.

Comment: Hi Devgeeks, thank you for your answer, but how about the security. anything you know how to implement it using ajax

Comment: What exactly are your security concerns?

Comment: exposing data to public, so if we have JSON web services, how to protect them without exposing to public

Comment: Like anyone else, I suppose. Authentication and API keys, etc? Encryption?